# White bug identify

Tags: identification, bugs

Today I saw those tiny white bugs in my plants.

[image]

[image]

It was on the lettuce, basil and peppermint. Is not a plague, just a group of them.

My first thought was it was whitefly, but they hasn't wings and doesn't fly.
Seen closer it seems like little white/transparent grasshoppers.

Thanks!

Edit: A method to get rid of it would be also nice!

Comment: Insects are not at all your problem.  Your plants look very anemic, have you given them any fertilizer at all?  Insects will come when plants are weak.  I see huge chemical deficiencies in this plant.  Please tell us more about your maintenance and practices with plants.  Fertilizer is as important as light and water. Again, too much will cause death but none is dumb.

Comment: Hi Stormy, this plant is not fertilized at all. My father bought it and he leave it with the same soil and pot that it came with. The plant eventually seemed to die, but months later it regrow as you can see. Also another tiny one is growing now. Should I buy fertilizer or there is some kind of homemade solution? Should I repot it? Is coconut soil with hummus good for peppermint? Thanks!

Comment: Edgar, yes, get sterilized potting soil and perhaps a slightly larger pot.  I am not able to see the size of your plant and the size of your pot.  Sterilized potting soil. You HAVE to add fertilizer; LESS IS BEST, more is death and none is dumb.

Comment: The safest bestus fertilizer for your needs is Osmocote14-14-14.  It is extended release and will last a good 4 to 6 months!  Make sure you have a drainage hole, only only sterilized potting soil without any water holding gimmicks or fertilizer!  Nothing else goes in that pot, nothing.  Leave 1" between the surface of the soil and the rim of the pot.  Healthy, vibrant, vigorous plants.  Vigorously growing plants are able to repel troublesome insects.  Only plants that have been weakened will have insects taking advantage.

Comment: Thanks Stormy! So, how should I do the process? Just puting coconut fiber without any earthworm humus and then the fertilizer? Or should I use universal potting soil (As it has water holding perlite)?

Comment: Just sterilized potting soil.  No water holding gimmicks NO fertilizer added in the product.  If you've ever tried sterilizing your own potting soil medium (very little actual soil soil) P U!!   You have to have all the NEUTRAL ingredients, ingredients that don't need decomposition so much, like Perlite, Vermiculite, Coco fiber, Peat Moss is an environment big issue, Sand...and such.  It is way smarter just to buy a cheap bag of potting soil.  Don't add anything else, except for a bit of fertilizer.  Insects aren't your plant's problem, it is being deficient in chemistry for photosynthesis.

Comment: ...and Perlite, Vermiculite aren't so much water holding materials as they are water 'shedding' materials.  This enables the soil to have less compaction more air available and better drainage.  Give HALF of the suggested amount on the directions of Osmocote.

Comment: And I have to mention that I see other issues as well; powdery mildew on top of the 'anemia'...just use that Osmocote. Half of what they recommend.  It is extended release and if you haven't fertilized at all THIS will get your plant strong again, strong enough to do battle with fungus/insects/disease (possible bit of virus that I can see).

Comment: Or write us in a few weeks for an update?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out **thrips** bugs. These make similar damage and are quite contagious.
Bear in mind that they are biologically insects (not relatives of spider mites) so they need different chemical agent to kill. Any insecticide will do.

[image]